# A simple way to make the code more readable for localizedStrings in Xcode

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I am mostly writing this for other newbie folks and to remind myself in a few years when I forget what I did

---

I had a long list of localized strings in the application I was building.  I really hated the lack of readability as I plodded my way through a whole bunch of statements like

```
[_myUILabelObject setText:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(_myString, applicationLanguage,nil)]
```

Then I was going to need another one that was different for UIButtons and UITextView and so on.  There had to be a better way.  What I wanted was something like

```
[_myUILabelObject translateMe:@"This text");
```

Comment: Why doesn't your call to `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` contain any actual text? It's supposed to have the actual text so it is readable.

Comment: good question.  In the general case it would.  There were two reasons I took the approach here. 1) I was trying to be somewhat generic here and convey the idea of extending the class rather than focusing on the text... sorry if that was confusing.  2) In my case, I have some fairly long text (see 2nd half of the discussion) and substituting it with a placeholder is pragmatic. It was actually @Zaph who pointed me to this in his response to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725483/standard-or-best-method-for-localizing-long-strings-for-ios

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I did:

I created a bunch of class extensions (technically categories) for each object:  UIButton, UILabel, UITextView... whatever I needed.

Each one has a simple .h file that simply declares that the extension is related to the main class.  Here's an example for my translateMe for UITextField:

```
@interface UITextField (translateMe)
- (void) translateMe: (NSString *) usingString;
@end
```

The first line tells the compiler that **translateMe** is going to be an extension of UITextField.

The second line tells the compiler that translateMe is expecting to be a method of UITextField that receives an NSString that I've called **usingString**.

Then in the .m implementation file, I've done this:

```
extern NSString *applicationLanguage;

- (void) translateMe: (NSString *) string {
    [self setText:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(string, applicationLanguage,nil)];
    [self sizeToFit];
}
```

The *applicationLanguage* string is a string that I set elsewhere based on the user's selection of language and it essentially is the name of the .strings file.

The rest of the code here simply includes all the laborious coding that I wanted to avoid in my ViewController's code.

Now the magic here is that one can create similar combinations of the .h and .m files for every object you have in your ViewControllers.  If you call all of the methods **translateMe**, then you don't have to worry at coding time which of the objects you're actually calling.  The result is you get something that looks simple like this:

```
[_standardDemoPlanTitle          translateMe:  @"Standard Demo Plan"];
[_linkSampleDemoVideoButton      translateMe:  @"Link to sample demo"];
[_linkCustomerPresentationButton translateMe:  @"Link to customer presentation"];
[_personalNotesTitle             translateMe:  @"Your Personal Notes"];
[_theSaveButton                  translateMe:  @"Save"];
[_emailPlanButton                translateMe:  @"Email this plan to a colleague"];
```

Note that the fact that some are buttons and some are labels (Titles) doesn't matter at all.

As an additional short cut, I learned from another post that it is possible to deal with long sections of text in a short way too.

Instead of:

```
[_longTextRequiredByLawyers translateMe: @"blah blah blah blah blah forever..."];
```

What I can do is to put in a short handle for the text in the implementation file and put the longer text in the .strings file.  Here's an example:

```
[longTextRequiredByLawyers translateMe: @"#lawyerText"];
```

by the way, the #-sign is not required, but I used it throughout my .m files as a personal reminder so that I knew that what was going to inserted did not necessarily match with what was in the prototype in the interface builder.

Then my *english.strings* file included something like this:

```
"#lawyerText" = "When in the course of human events it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the bonds which have connected them with another and to assume among the powers of the earth the separate and equal station to which the laws of God...";
```

and my *spanish.strings* file had the translation:

```
"#lawyerText" = "En México no hay abogados, entonces el texto es mas corto.";
```

You could do the same thing for Albanian and Klingon.

So, key tricks (or good programming ideas here):

1. Use Cateogries to extend the class definitions for the UI objects you have on your pages.  Those categories can include everything you need to make your main code more readable.
2. Name the method the same thing in every extension so that you don't have to think about it when you do the magic in your .m files.
3. Use short handles for long strings of text and jam the longer stuff into the .strings files.

One thing I wish I had figured out:

I now have a long list of .h files that I now have to #include at the top of all of my ViewController .m files. I wish that I could have a .h file that #includes all of the translateMe .h files... kind of a nested .h.

- UIButton+translateMe.h
- UITextView+translateMe.h
- UILabel+translateMe.h
- UIButton+translateMe.h
- and so on

Wouldn't it be nice to have a single .h file, perhaps allMyTranslates.h that has the list above inside of it, and then I just include allMyTranslates.h in the code I am writing.

I would end up replacing:

```
#include "UIButton+translateMe.h"
#include "UITextView+translateMe.h"
#include "UILabel+translateMe.h"
#include "UIButton+translateMe.h"
#include and so on
```

with this

```
#include "allMyTranslateHeaders.h"
```

Well, there you go... a few notes from a newbie... All the experts have been helpful of course, but every once in a while we need a note like this one to get us over the hump!

Comment: Zaph...say more.  If there's something to be learned here, I'd love to hear it.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If there are others who will work with your code they will not understand what you have done. Not to mention the added complexity of several Categories. Sure `NSLocalizedString` is ugly but it is well understood and expected. Your solution is also missing the comment which is useful to a translator to obtain context of the usage.

Comment: Thanks.  The concept of extensions to existing classes is a natural part all OOP.  Your comment about documenting it well has to indicate the concept of extensions.  Is there a conventional way to do this?

Comment: Class extensions are possible but not usually a good idea, one should have a compelling reason to pollute Apple supplied classes. They are not a part of OOP in general, they seems to be unique to Objective-C. When one writes code the key concept should be to be as clear as possible to future readers. The measurement unit is "WTFs/minute", a lower values are better.

Comment: Love the metric (WTFs/minute).  Thanks for the dialog.  I think I understand your position and if your perspective is mainstream (based on your REP, I'm guessing it is) I'm kind of mourning the effort I put into understand the class extensions and trying to make it work.  In my case, I think it makes the code imminently more readable due to the simplification of the flow within the code for the ViewController, but I understand your point that you'd have to go find the translateMe method... looking to the #includes, etc.

Comment: Don't mourn the time you spent, that's how we learn. I've learned many things not-to-do by having done them. Cleaner, seems so bit that is not the only measure.